# Reorder with recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

How to use recursive function to reordered array with even indices first and then odd indices?
For example:
input: [5, 2, 4, 9]
output: [5, 4, 2, 9]

I want to improve this code.

```js
let arrayB = [],
  arrayOdd = [],
  arrayEven = [];
let i = 0;

const reorder = (arrayA) => {
  if (arrayA.length >= 2) {
    if (i < arrayA.length) {
      i === 0 || i % 2 === 0 ? arrayEven.push(arrayA[i]) : arrayOdd.push(arrayA[i]);
      i++;
      arrayB = [...arrayEven, ...arrayOdd];
      reorder(arrayA);
    } else {
      arrayOdd = [];
      arrayEven = [];
      i = 0;
    }
    return arrayB;
  }
}

console.log(reorder([4, 8, 12, 16]));

console.log(reorder([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

Comment: why not just browsing all the elements and push the odd in an array and the even in the other ? no need for recursion here. Something like `arrayA.forEach((x, i) => { if (i%2 === 0) arrayEven .push(x) else arrayOdd.push(x) })`

Comment: What is the problem, and what are you want to improve?

Comment: My leader just want to use recursion and he want I don't use global variable and minimalist storage

Comment: This code seems to work, so I'd say it's more suited to [codereview.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why you'd need a recursive function. This should do it:

```js
const reorder = (a) => [...a.filter((_, i) => !(i % 2)), ...a.filter((_, i) => i % 2)];

console.log(reorder([4, 8, 12, 16]));
console.log(reorder([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

---

Because you stipulate your in comments that you have instructions to use a recursive function with minimum space requirements, here's a solution that uses [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to modify the array in place:

```js
const reorder = (a, offset = 2) => {
  if (offset < a.length) {
    a.splice(offset / 2, 0, ...a.splice(offset, 1));
    return reorder(a, offset + 2);
  }
  return a;
};

console.log(reorder([4, 8, 12, 16]));
console.log(reorder([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

<sub>Note that, like the `Array.prototype.sort()` function, the above function only returns the array for convenience. No new array is created.</sub>

Comment: Because my leader want to use recursive function

Comment: My leader just want to use recursion and he want I don't use global variable and minimalist storage

Comment: Oh, so you're supposed to reorder the array in place? I.e. without creating a new array?

Comment: I don't know reorder the array in place

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by using sort method of array. but for that you might need to use map to get index and then converting back to values.

```js
const isOdd = n => n % 2 === 1;
const reorder = input => input.map((value, index) => ({index, value})).sort((a,b) => 
    isOdd(a.index) ? 1 : isOdd(b.index) ? -1 : 0).map(({value}) => value);

console.log(reorder([4, 8, 12, 16]));

console.log(reorder([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

Comment: This sorts on based on whether the values are even or odd, not the indices.

Comment: Moreover, the comparator doesn't return consistent values `compare(2, 4)` is `1` and `compare(4, 2)` is also `1`. Which makes both results wrong - the first one should be `[4, 12 8, 16]` yet there are no odd values, so nothing gets sorted, while the second one *has* odd values which leads to `[9, 7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8]` instead of `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8]`

Comment: `isEven` works the opposite of what its name implies (i.e., returns false if n is even).

Comment: The second half of the sorted arrays is now reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using global variables.

```js
const reorder = (arrayA, arrayOdd = [], arrayEven = []) => {
    if (arrayA.length >= 1)
        arrayEven.push(arrayA.shift());
    if (arrayA.length >= 1) {
        arrayOdd.push(arrayA.shift());   
        reorder(arrayA, arrayOdd, arrayEven);    
    }
    return [...arrayEven, ...arrayOdd];
}

console.log(reorder([4, 8, 12, 16]));
  
console.log(reorder([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would choose to do this recursively, but this seems to do it:

```js
const evenThenOdd = ([e = undefined, o = undefined, ...xs], evens = [], odds = []) => 
  e == undefined
    ? [...evens, ...odds]
    : o == undefined 
      ? evenThenOdd ( xs, [...evens, e] [odds] )
      : evenThenOdd ( xs, [...evens, e], [...odds, o] )


console .log (
  evenThenOdd ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
  //~> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
)
```

We keep `evens` and `odds` arrays of values.  The base case, when there is nothing left in the array, is to just concatenate those two arrays.  The other two cases are when there is one item left and where there are two or more items left.  If the `undefined` values are legitimate elements of your array you want to handle, then add `const None = Symbol()`, and replace each `undefined` with `None`.

---

A cleaner, non-recursive solution might look like this:

```js
const evenThenOdd = (xs) => [
  ...xs.filter((_, i) => i % 2 == 0),
  ...xs.filter((_, i) => i % 2 == 1),
]
```